# Filtering list with managed metadata field dose not work in iFrame

Tags: listview, iframe, filtering, sharepoint-2013

I am working on a publishing site. As required, a view of pages library needs to be displayed on a page. The view contains a managed metadata field.

If access the page directly, the view can be filtered with any of the fields. 
But if access the page via iFrame on other sites or even the same site, filter the view with managed metadata field, I cannot get any response from server. 
Filtering works fine for all types of site column except managed metadata.

I tried to isolate the issue: 
when trying to filter with a field, dynamically a drop down menu will be generated based on a out of box template. Each item on the drop down menu has an onmenuclick event. 
For a simply type field the event is:

```
onmenuclick="javascript:HandleFilter(event, 'url')"
```

but for a managed metadata filed the event is:

```
onmenuclick="javascript:window.parent.HandleFilter(window.parent.event, 'url')"
```

I am not allowed to modify the out of box template. 
So please help, is there any solutions or hotfix? Any thoughts are appreciated. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
                function fixFilters() {
                    $("[id^=FilterIframe]").on("load", function () {                
                        $(".ms-vh-div[fieldtype='TaxonomyFieldType']").on("mouseover",".ms-MenuUIULItem",function() {
                            var old = $(this).attr("onMenuClick");
                            if (typeof old != "undefined") {
                                var newString = old.replace(/window\.parent\./g,"");
                                $(this).attr("onMenuClick",newString);
                            }
                        }); 
                    });         
                };
                _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("fixFilters");
```

The above works for me with reasonable reliability.

Comment: There's no rush to answer questions (especially an older one like this one), so if you're still working on your answer it's best to wait until you're done before posting it.